# How to display images in pairs using AngularJS in html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm developing an application using AngularJS. I would like to display a list of products in a page, but in pairs, so each row will show two images. The products are loaded using REST services. So let's assume we have already all the products loaded in the collection "products". The code I use to iterate over the products is:

```
<div id="products">
    <div class="row" data-ng-repeat="product in products">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <img alt="" 
                 data-ng-src="{{product.pathToImage}}" 
                 height="300"
                 width="200px">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Like this all the products are displayed each one in a row, is there a way or can someone give me some idea to iterate the collection but displaying two (or more) images in the same row?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: sort the products into an array of array-pairs where the  array pairs contain two products each. You can then do a double ng-repeat.

Ng-repeat=pair in pairs 
     Ng-repeat product in pairs
          Img code here

Option 2: do it the "angular way" and create your own custom angular filter that massages the data into a format that can be looped over in a single ng-repeat. You can apply the filter in the ng-repeat using a "|". I'm not going to give you the code because you need to spend some time on your own implementing some basic custom filters to understand how they work and there are several blogs online you can refer to. Egghead.io is a wonderful resource.

Comment: I'll go for option 2. Thanks!